# javascript electron: how to increase performance and prevent crashes when working with big amounts of data

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, electron

With my app, when I want to process data there is a threshold that above it, chrome (electron) cannot cope and crashes. Looking at RAM and CPU it shouldn't happen (CPU and memory below 60%), but the amount of data is high enough (data parsing of 500Mb files) so that it makes sense.

But still, is there a way to workaround this? For example, I have tried to change

```
let lines = file.split("\n");
// lines is an array of 500,000
for (let i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
 parse(lines[i]);
```

for an async call

```
let parsing = function(i){
 return new Promise(function(resolve){
  if (i < lines.length) {
   parse(lines[i]);
   i++;
   resolve(parsing(i));
  } else
   resolve();
 });
};

let lines = file.split("\n");
var i = 0;
resolve(parsing(i));
```

And even including a timeOut every n lines to let Chrome-electron "breathe". But the problem has indeed worsen since it crashes much earlier (it processes a lower number of lines). You can see that there is a problem building up since the `console.log` messages start to get slower and slower before the crash.

So the question is, is there a way that I can workaround this? Or these files are just too large and I'll have to wait for new hardware iterations that can handle them (?)

EDIT:
I haven't been able to solve it by using a worker. While the sizes were copied quite fast (I'd say in few seconds), the loop crashed at the very beginning.

And I have improved a little bit but still largely not enough by combining the async call to do it not for every line but for every 5,000 lines. The loop lasts a little bit longer.

Comment: Is your javascript running ok outside the electron enclosure? I've got a running electron app, that holds a big document, but not as big as yours. But it does without problem. Try to be a bit more specific on the type of data, or type of process you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It is text data, everything is within the electron enclousure, I have to split in lines, and then every line split in tabs, and then organize the data into an object for later work on it. The file sizes depend on each user and are experimentally originated.

Comment: In my case my files are much smaller and everything works as expected. Now I am facing these sizes and I'm trying to see if there is a solution

Comment: Did you try using streams?

Comment: @PrashanthChandra what are streams?

Comment: It's another way of passing data asynchronously, similar to Promises. Unlike Promises which can only return a single value, streams are for handling multiple values e.g. chunks in a file, chunks in an HTTP response, etc.  
Check this out: https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook  
and this: https://github.com/workshopper/stream-adventure

Comment: @PrashanthChandra but this refers to passing data. My problem is not about this, is about Chrome crashing when coping with too much data, even when it is done by a worker

Comment: It's not just about passing data. With your first approach, you are forcing node to handle the entire file in memory. Your 2nd approach to handle this asynchronously was in the right direction, but creating a promise for every line puts even more pressure on GC, and the for-loop is still synchronous. What you want to do is to read the file as a stream, maybe find a module that splits the stream by new line, then map/transform each chunk with your parse function

Comment: My assumption is that by letting node stream the data instead of a for loop, it should automatically "breathe" when necessary, and will reduce GC pressure since you'll never have the entire file in memory at any point

Comment: Now I get your point (and makes complete sense), I'll read your two links to see if I see a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue of looping through a large number of lines by just eliminating the line that is already read.

in my case, it was simply by doing this

```
for (let i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
 pieces = lines[i].split("\t");
 lines[i] = ''; // <- here
```

By deleting each read line I have increased the performance I'd say very significantly.

However, the next bottleneck is when constructing an object (after the lines are well parsed) since it becomes too large and it makes Chrome crash. What I conclude is that I am probably reaching the limit for javascript in Electron-Chrome in managing with complex and large objects.

Answer (score 2):

The issue I believe you're having is that your code reads the entire file into memory. Streaming the lines from the file instead should improve performance.

I tried it out and evaluated multiple modules ([byline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/byline), [split](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split), [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)) to handle reading by newline. `readline` had the best performance out of the three, so that's what I'll demonstrate.

Here's an example where I read from a file, uppercased each line then wrote the result to another file. If you don't care about using the data after parsing it, just ignore all the `rs` code.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline')
const stream = require('stream')

const lineReader = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('dummy.txt')
})
const rs = new stream.Readable
rs._read = function () {}
rs.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('transformed.txt'))

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  rs.push(parse(line))
})
lineReader.on('close', function () {
  // when all lines have been read
  // this signals that the stream has ended
  rs.push(null)
})

function parse(chunk) {
  return chunk.toUpperCase()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will see if this helps. But before that, I suspect that the problem appears when the object(s) is starting to be too large and at the end it crashes, rather than processing too many lines. But I could be wrong, I'll check it hopefully with your answer :)

Comment: I've added a self-answer since I've found a way very simple to boost the parsing. I however cannot prevent Chrome crashing when working with very large data structures. Perhaps I should store parts of the data and dynamically load them when required. But in any case I cannot use your suggestions, but thanks since I didn't know about these modules :)